# Storing file content in DB

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I am making a model in which i have a `FileField`. I want to store the file content in a database column, instead of file path. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Files belong on the filesystem.

Comment: How much binary data do you expect to store in the database? There is a big difference between storing a few binary objects in the database when compared to storing thousands of large binary files.

Comment: Yes. What is the rationale of that decision? Why not store them on the FS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is very easy

just overide save method in admin

```
filecontent=form.cleaned_data.get('upload_file')  
data =filecontent.read()
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("update filecontent set filecontent=(%s) where id=(%s)",[data,obj.id])
connection.connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

this will store filecontent in db column filecontent of table filecontent

Comment: This won't work. The first binary file you try to save with non-ASCII characters will blow it up. You need to encode it first using base64, and then decode it when reading it out of the database.

Answer (score 24):

Disregard the naysayers. If you want to have full control over your content, put the files in a blob field in the database.  I generally also keep the filename in a separate field, so I can reconstruct the file as necessary (that way you keep the extension, which ties it to a file type in most operating systems).

Be sure to store the actual blob data in a separate table, only connected to your filename / extra info table via an id ... that way you don't sacrifice any performance when dealing with any information related to the file other than the content itself.

What the naysayers fail to realize, is that databases are simply an extremely optimized form of file system.  Bytes are bytes and disc sectors are disc sectors.  Databases are simply much better at organizing and searching those bytes than file systems are.  Not to mention, databases implement much more stringent security than most file systems and are better maintained (with backups, support staff etc.).

Comment: i only want to store the filecontent in db column of a table ,not interested in wasting table for it.I can regain the file content again in same patern.

Comment: Thank you for a little reality check. I've always felt Django's default aversion to storing files in the database is overly simplistic. Even if you want to serve them from the database, you could always wrap your model with a caching layer, to have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question, but there's been some good code written since then to allow this option. Specially, see [django-database-files](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-database-files), which will use Django's storage API to make all FileFields and ImageFields store their contents in the database. There's also a [fork](https://github.com/h3/django-database-files) to cache the files locally on the filesystem, to overcome the biggest caveat of using the database, which is latency.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about simply storing it in a Binary column? You can then store collection of bytes. And if the filename is important to you as well, you can store that in an additional name column.